# Assign multiple column values to JSON php array using mysql

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, arrays, json

I have to make a JSON ajax request and have an array in return.

i found this code on multiple other questions (edited to my problem):

```
var hej[];
function ajax_search(){ 
    $.getJSON('test.php',function(response){
    var data = response.get_response;
    for (i in data){
      hej.push([i,data[i]]);
    }
alert(hej[0]);
}
```

In the php part, i have a database from which i need the data i have have 5 columns pr. row.  I only have one row, and i need all five columns in the array.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM 'table'
   LIMIT 1 OFFSET $i"; //random offset
$result = mysql_query($sql);

$storeArray = Array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $storeArray[0]=$row['column1'];
    $storeArray[1]=$row['column2'];
    $storeArray[2]=$row['column3'];
    $storeArray[3]=$row['column4'];
    $storeArray[4]=$row['column5'];
}
$json = json_encode($storeArray);
echo $json;
```

I know im doing something wrong, and i am new to programming. I need to be able to access all column values in my javascript after the call and use them in other functions, but i cant get it to return.

I would really appriciate help, with both the javascript and the php if there are errors in either.

Comment: What is the test.php script output? (Just open it in a browser and see what it prints)

Comment: why don't you just `json_encode($row)`?

Comment: @Nemaden How can i access every column after that then?

Comment: I don't see the output if it's not an empty string :)

Comment: By it's name, e.g. `response.column1`

Comment: i am really new, could you pass me an example on the php code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```
function ajax_search(){ 
    $.getJSON('test2.php',function(response){
        // response.column1
        // response.column2
        // response.column3

        // for array push:
        var hej = [];
        $.each(response, function(key, val) {
             hej.push(val);
        });
        alert(hej[0]); // it will alert column1
    });

}
```

and MySQL:

```
$sql = "SELECT `column1`, `column2`, `column3`, `column4`, `column5` FROM `table` LIMIT 1 OFFSET $i"; //random offset
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$json = json_encode($row);
echo $json;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why use response.get_response?

```
var hej[];
function ajax_search(){ 
    $.getJSON('test.php',function(data){
    $.each(data, function (i,item) {
      hej.push([i,item]);
    }
alert(hej[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**Javascript Code:**

```
var hej[];
function ajax_search(){
    $.getJSON('test.php',function(response){
        $.each(response.results, function(key, val) {
            hej.push(val);
        });
        alert(hej[0]);
    });
}
```

**PHP Code:**

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM 'table' LIMIT 1 OFFSET $i"; //random offset
$result = mysql_query($sql);

$storeArray = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $storeArray[0]= $row['column1'];
    $storeArray[1]=$row['column2'];
    $storeArray[2]=$row['column3'];
    $storeArray[3]=$row['column4'];
    $storeArray[4]=$row['column5'];
}

$json = json_encode( array('results' => $storeArray ) );
echo $json;
?>
```

Hope this helps.